# AudioSource value for USB microphone on Android

Tags: android, audio, usb

An audio capture application on rooted MK809/Android 4.1.1. There is no internal mic so I am trying to use a USB one which is correctly detected as "USB Audio Device" in *Settings/Sound/Sound Devices Manager/Sound Input Devices* when connected.

What is this device's AudioSource value to pass into AudioRecord constructor (first argument). I tried every one in MediaRecorder.AudioSource, none worked. I am only interested in reading the capture buffer, not saving into a file.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question. The following values did work: DEFAULT, MIC, CAMCORDER, probably others too as it is the only input device.

I was trying to use sample rate of 48000 (works on Windows) and AudioRecord creation failed with:

ERROR/AudioRecord(1615): Could not get audio input for record source 1
ERROR/AudioRecord-JNI(1615): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
ERROR/AudioRecord-Java(1615): [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

Somewhat misleading info considering that a call to getMinBufferSize() with the same set of agruments does not return an error as it is supposed to. I assumed that it was a valid sample rate for the device. Setting it to 44100 (guranteed) fixed the problem.

USB audio input devices do work on Android, Jelly Bean at least. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, this is implementation specific (it can differ between different platform vendors and OEMs).

On the devices I've worked on, the USB accessory's mic would be chosen if the AudioSource is `DEFAULT`, `MIC` or `VOICE_RECOGNITION`, and the only sample rates supported in the audio HAL for USB audio recording were 8, 16 and 48 kHz (although the AudioFlinger is able to resample to other rates within a certain range).

Comment: can you please answer my question about disabling automatic audio routing or routing to USB audio peripherals? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77436297/change-audio-source-for-speech-recognition-android